# Method is not working in Java as I want it to print out my phone number

Tags: java

public class Methods {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int myNum = myNumber();
    System.out.println(myNum);

}   
static int myNumber(){
    return 03233574633;
}
```

}

When I call a method to display my phone number on screen, it display something this 443480475..

Why is this happening in Java Programming.. Please help

Answer (score 3):

The `0` prefix means that `03233574633` is an octal number which equals `443480475` decimal. You can use a String to represent the phone number.

Answer (score 2):

Starting a literal number with a 0 makes it base 8 (octal). You want base 10. You can easily store your phone number as a String to avoid this.